# Product purchase and money change based on money bills the user has

Tags: c#

I've been stuck on this problem for a week, I searched and the results I found don't seem to fit with what I want to do.

**Problem:**
A person will purchase something and the cashier will give back the change based on the person's dollar bills.

**What I've done:** I'm detecting how much money the buyer has in total and the amount of each dollar bill, comparing if the buyer has the required amount or not.

But now I need to get the amount of required bills the buyer has to subtract from the purchase price and remove them to complete the payment. A greedy algorithm is OK for me here, I can start from highest bill and go down from there until the sum of his bills are less or equal than the purchase total. Then the cashier just give the remain

I've the code to give the change, which is a simple greedy algorithm by dividing and getting the remainder of division. I believe to solve my problem, I could do something similar to what I done for the money change.

The bills are: 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100.

**Code example:**

```
int Value = 150 //value that needs to be paid
int q100 = 1; //dollar bills amount that needs to subtract from Value
int q50 = 0;
int q20 = 0;
int q10 = 5; //this example I've one $50 dollar bill and five $10, how can I subtract from here no matter how many bills I've
int q5 = 0;
int q1 = 0;
int q05 = 0;
decimal Total = 0;

int Total = (n100 * 100) + (n50 * 50) + (n20 * 20) + (n10 * 10) + (n5 * 5) + (n1 * 1);

if(Value > Total)
{
    //Doesn't have enough money
    return;
}

//stuck here
```

Can anyone give me a lead to go on? I might be searching in the wrong place.

**EDITED:** I came with the solution, following Jason Lang answer partially.

```
for (int i = billValues.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) // biggest FIRST
{
    // basically keep paying with e.g. hundreds as long as the amount 
    // left is 100+, etc, then go on to 50's etc

    while (amountLeftToPay > 0 && myBills[i] > 0)
    {
        amountLeftToPay -= billValues[i];
        myBills[i]--;
        paidBills[i]++;
    }
}
```

**What happened:** myBills are setting the values before anything, this for/while iterates until AmountLeftToPay is 0 or less than 0 while saving the bills that the customer paid. (The bills are later removed in other function, it doesn't work with basic C#, it is based off from a framework from a game.)

Then I made the negative value become positive multiplying by -1. That value is handed to the function to be converted as change.
Here is the code for a little test I did on a console application for debugging: http://pastebin.com/GekLLjB3

At the end myBills values are the customers leftover bills before receiving any change, paidBills is the removed bills.

Comment: Your description of the problem is a bit weird. Your "problem" statement makes it sound like the cashier is working out the bills but then your "what I've done" section describes the customer working out the bills. Which is it?

Comment: It's because I'm working on a framework to develop a plugin, so I tried to convert to normal C# language. The code checks for the customer bills and makes him give all the highest bill until the amount paid is less than the amount required to be paid, then the cashier just gives the difference in the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, any time you're making a big number of variables like that with numbers on them, convert that to a single array instead. Much neater, and it's almost always better.

```
int[] billValues = {1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100};
```

Then you can have arrays for your starting bills, what was paid and what change you got, without having an explosion of variable names:

```
int[] myBills = new int[6]; // which bills I have
int[] paidBills = new int[6]; // what bills I paid
int[] changeBills = new int[6]; // what bills I got as change
```

These match the "slots" in the billValue array, so you don't actually need to make all those separate variables.

Have the pay amount separate:

```
int amountToPay = 150;
```

Then, you can run some while loops to deduct bills from the correct arrays and add them to other arrays. The first thing you want to do is loop through your bills and deduct the largest bills that are equal or less than the amountToPay. You need to keep track of the amount left to pay, as each bill is handed over.

```
int amountLeftToPay = amountToPay;
```

Then, deduct the biggest bill that fits

```
for(int i = billValues.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) // biggest FIRST
{
    // basically keep paying with e.g. hundreds as long as the amount 
    // left is 100+, etc, then go on to 50's etc

    while (billValues[i] <= amountLeftToPay && myBills[i] > 0)
    {
        amountLeftToPay -= billValues[i];
        myBills[i] --;
        paidBills[i] ++;
    }
}
```

At this point, all bills that you have that fit inside the amount to pay have been paid. There could be a situation now however where the amount left to pay is greater than zero, but it's less than any particular bill that you have. To sort that out, you need to find out what is the smallest bill that's greater than the amount left to pay. So you need to loop up, this time:

```
int billToUse = -1; // -1 will mean not found

for(int i = 0; i < billValues.Length; i++) // smallest first
{
    if(amountLeftToPay <= billValues[i] && myBills[i] > 0)
    {
        billToUse = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here we want to record how much change is owed, if any

```
int amountOwedAsChange = 0;

if(billToUse >= 0) // i.e. one was found
{
    amountOwedAsChange = billValues[billToUse] - amountLeftToPay;
    amountLeftToPay = 0;
}
```

Righto, this is the home stretch. Working out what bills are owed as change is basically the same as what we did when we worked out what bills to pay with, except we can assume that the cash register has unlimited bills. But you could actually convert the original "paying bills" code into a function, and model what's in the cash register so that they only pay with what they have. Once you break things into functions that becomes much, much easier. You just model the cash register as another "person" who themselves have a myBills array. But for now, we hard-code the simpler version where cash registers always have bills they need:

```
for(int i = billValues.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) // biggest FIRST
{
    while (billValues[i] <= amountOwedAsChange)
    {
        amountOwedAsChange -= billValues[i];
        changeBills [i] ++;
    }
}
```

So at this point, amountLeftToPay and amountOwedAsChange are both zero, and the information has been packed into myBills, and changeBills, and you can cycle through those and print out text describing what was paid and what change you got.

For added points, you can expand this to cover coins very easily. You just code everything in cents, and multiply all dollar values by 100, expanding out the billValues table (and increasing the size of the other arrays to match) as needed.

Comment: I'm working on your code. I'm using functions for this, but there is something I don't understand, does this predict any amount to pay? Because in (billValues[i] <= amountLeftToPay && myBills[i] > 0) you tested billValues (which are 10, 50, 100, for example) with the amount left to be paid, which can be over 100.

Doesn't matter how many bills I've, it just needs to be more (the sum) than the amount to be paid. (I might have misunderstood that part), thanks for the answer

Comment: It works down. e.g. it starts with hundred dollar bills. If the amountLeftToPay is 300, then it would loop on hundreds three times, shift 3 bills over to "paidBills" for that denomination, meanwhile, it deducts that value from amountLeftToPay. So amountLeftToPay would be zero then, and it recorded that three hundreds were paid. The trick is in the <= "less than or equal to". e.g. if you said "pay 350", it would keep knocking 100's off, but then it gets to 50 left, and 100 is not "less than or equal" to 50, so it moves on to trying 50's. Clearer? :D

Comment: One thing I didn't write in the answer is that at the end you could still have some amountLeftToPay at the end. So you can test for that and say "you didn't have enough money", but because the amount paid is recorded in paidBills, you can decide what to do with that at that point. Or, you could do a test like your one at the start, but using a loop to add up how much total money you have.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing if the AmountToBePaid is bigger than what I've with me, as I mentioned on my example, it wasn't very clear. I'm going to test, if it work I could post the entire solution, but it is not in simple C#, I'm using a framework to make changes into a game.

Comment: it does not work for { 1, 3, 4, 5, 8 } amountToPay = 10 and restriction to one coins per nominal (one coin for every coin type)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you can breakdown the amount into the required notes:

```
var bills = new [] { 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, };
var value = 150;
var breakdown =
    bills
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .Aggregate(new { value, bills = new List<int>() },
            (a, b) =>
            {
                var v = a.value;
                while (v >= b)
                {
                    a.bills.Add(b);
                    v -= b;
                }
                return new { value = v, a.bills };  
            })
        .bills
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new { Bill = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

That gives me:

[image: bills]

You can easily extend this to account for coins too.

```
var bills = new double[] { 0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, };
var value = 213.47;
var breakdown =
    bills
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .Aggregate(new { value, bills = new List<double>() },
            (a, b) =>
            {
                var v = a.value;
                while (v >= b)
                {
                    a.bills.Add(b);
                    v -= b;
                }
                return new { value = v, a.bills };  
            })
        .bills
        .GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new { Bill = x.Key, Count = x.Count() });
```

That gives:

[image: coins]